# How to get part from JSON using 'response.stream.bytesToString()' instead of "(response.body) ['data']"

Tags: flutter, api, dart, http

Edit 1:
I am new to Flutter, and coding altogether, so please answer in simple terms.
I can get a JSON string from this API: [https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1][1]. using     `jsonDecode(response.body)`

And I can also get specific part within this JSON using
`jsonDecode(response.body)['data']  // 'data' is a List[]`

But Postman, generates this completely different code to get data from api.
Postman uses  `response.stream.bytesToString());`

Now I want to keep using Postman's auto generated code, but tweek it such that I get only the List, 'data', from the API.

## My full code is:

```
    class ApiService {
        
        Future<List<UserModel>> getData() async {
        
          try{
            Response response = await get( Uri.parse('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2'));
            List result = await jsonDecode(response.body)['data'];
        
            if (response.statusCode == 200) {
              print(response);
              print('');
              print(response.body);
              print('');
              print(result);
              print('');
              return result.map((e) => UserModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
          }
          else {
              print(response.reasonPhrase);
              throw Exception(response.reasonPhrase);
          }
          } catch(e){
            print('Error AA gaya \n\n\n $e') ;
            throw e;
          }
        }
    }



------------

Postman generated code is:
==========================

    var request = http.Request('GET', Uri.parse('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2'));
    
    a
    http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
    
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
    }
    else {
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
    }

  [1]: https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1
```

Comment: How look your print and JSON object that comes from Postman?

Comment: Ovidiu Uşvat
can you rephrase? I dont understand.

Comment: You have some prints in your code. Can you please provide them? Also, you said that everything is fine with postman, can you provide the response from postman?

Answer (score 1):

your code is correct but the way you parse is wrong

```
  Future<List<UserModel>> getData() async {
try{
  Response response = await get( Uri.parse('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2'));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var jdata =  jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(response);
    print('');
    print(response.body);
    print('');
    print(jdata);
    print('');
    return jdata['data'].map((e) => UserModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }
  else {
    print(response.reasonPhrase);
    throw Exception(response.reasonPhrase);
  }
} catch(e){
  print('Error AA gaya \n\n\n $e') ;
  throw e;
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry But I needed to tweek the Postman's autogenerated code, such that it gets me only specific part of Json from the Api. e.g ['data']